# Não consigo fazer update porque ele não está recuperando o id php pdo

Tags: php, pdo, select, lista

Aqui é para recuperar no `html`:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $administrador = new Administrador();        
        $mostrar = $administrador->listar_id($_GET["id"]);
  }

<form action="Crud.php" method="post" id="none">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $mostrar['id']?>">
            Nome:<input type="text" id="none" name="nome" value="<?php echo $mostrar['nome']?>">
            email:<input type="text" id="none" name="email" value="<?php echo $mostrar['email']?>">
            cpf:<input type="text" id="none" name="cpf" value="<?php echo $mostrar['cpf']?>">
            salario:<input type="text" id="none" name="salario" value="<?php echo $mostrar['salario']?>">
            <input type="submit" value="atualizar" name="atualizar">
```

Aqui é o meu arquivo `Crud.php,` que faz a ligação do `html` com a classe.

```
if(isset($_POST["atualizar"])){// Chamada Método atualizar
                $administrador = new Administrador();
                $administrador->atualizar(strip_tags(trim($_POST['id'])),(strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']))),(trim($_POST['email'])),(trim($_POST['cpf'])),(trim($_POST['salario'])));
            }
```

O método `atualizar` está funcionando perfeitamente, o que está dando pau é que não está recuperando o `id`.

```
public function atualizar($id,$nome,$email,$cpf,$salario){
        $sql_atualizar = "UPDATE administrador SET nome='$nome', email='$email', cpf='$cpf', salario='$salario' WHERE id = '$id'";        
        try{
            $query_atualizar = $this->conn()->prepare($sql_atualizar);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':cpf',$cpf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':salario',$salario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->execute();
            print_r($query_atualizar);
            //echo "<script>alert('Administrador alterado com sucesso! ')</script>";
            //header('location: Index.php');

        }catch(PDOException $err){
            echo " Erro: ".$err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Como postei logo a cima:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $administrador = new Administrador();        
        $mostrar = $administrador->listar_id($_GET["id"]);
  }
```

No caso, se faço isso da certo, tira o get id  e coloca o id direto, mas não é isso que quero.

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $administrador = new Administrador();        
        $mostrar = $administrador->listar_id("10");
  }
```

assim ele trás todos os resultados do id 10, resumindo o que devo fazer para ele recuperar o id com o Get?

Esse e o meu método lista por id da minha classe:

```
public function listar_id($id){       
        try{
            $lista = ("SELECT * FROM administrador WHERE id = '$id'");
            $mostra_lista = $this->conn()->prepare($lista);
            $mostra_lista->bindValue(":id", $id,PDO::PARAM_INT);//pegando a id e substituindo por id
            $mostra_lista->execute();// Query e executado sempre que for uma lista comum, no caso da algo mais restrito e preferencial usar exec ou prepare

            //pegando só um valor

            if($mostra_lista->rowCount() == 1):// COntador
                return $mostra_lista->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            endif;
        }catch(PDOException $err){
            echo " Erro: ".$err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tirando o fato que vc está passado as variáveis direto na instrução(tratar isso depois), não dá para saber de vem o id, vem de um link? coloque essa informação na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução do meu problema o script agora funciona

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   $id = filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);// Atribuindo a variável $id o valor inteiro no metodo get id
   $administrador = new Administrador();
   $id = $administrador->listar_id($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é bem simples:

Seu form está assim:

```
<form action="Crud.php" method="post" id="none">
```

Ou seja ele está utilizando o método POST e no seu código PHP você está tentando recuperar o `id` que teria sido enviado via método GET

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
           |
           -- Deveria ser $_POST["id"]
```

Ou o seu form deveria ser:

```
<form action="Crud.php" method="get" id="none">
```

Esse é o problem mais óbvio do seu código. Mesmo mudando o que foi sugerido você poderá encontrar mais alguns problemas relacionados com essa troca de métodos HTTP. Recomendo uma leitura sobre isso. O melhores links são em inglês, como o do [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), mas já que estamos no SO português, leia este artigo: [Como funciona os métodos get e post](http://www.comocriarsites.com/html/como-funciona-os-metodos-get-e-post-diferencas/)

Comment: `$_GET["id"]` talvez tenha sido definido em um link, por isso a verificação.

Comment: @rray Pois é, talvez você tenha razão, mas pelo código fornecido não dá para ter certeza. Pelo menos ele poderá ter uma ideia do que pode estar errado.

Comment: obrigado, mas depois de tanto quebrar a cabeça consegui, por isso amo programar, essas quebras de cabeça que faz essa profissão tão fascinante. Eu já tinha tentado isso mas tbm deu erro, na verdade eu só precisava atribuir na variável. Então ficou assim.

Comment: if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $id = filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);// Atribuindo a variável $id o valor inteiro no metodo get id
        $administrador = new Administrador(); 
        $id = $administrador->listar_id($id);
    }

Comment: eu tinha feito assim if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $administrador = new Administrador();        
        $mostrar = $administrador->listar_id($_GET["id"]);
  }

Comment: @AlisonPaulo Que bom que resolveu! Você deveria adicionar sua solução como resposta e marcar como correta!